# How to fix no sound in headphone on Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, kubuntu

I have just installed Kubuntu 20.04 and there is no sound for my headphone. I tried `alsactl restore` and it worked but when i restart, this problem happen again.

Comment: Hi! Type alsamixer into a terminial and see if the bar over "headphone" is turned down? Failing that, edit your question with the make and model number of your computer and it might help people answer you :)

Comment: It worked! Thank you ^^

Comment: Yay! I'm so glad. I'll add this as the answer then. Happy listening to you!

Answer (score 0):

- Open a terminal
- Type in `alsamixer`
- See if the bar over "headphone" is turned down?
- you can navigate to it and turn it up using the arrow keys on the keyboard